# Appending zero's infront using HQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Input : 1092-04-1

I have loaded the above data as string. I need to append zero in front, if the length of the 1st string is less than 5.

Similarly if the length of the 2nd string is less than 3 and if the length of the 3rd string is less than 2 using HQL.

Desired Output: 01092-004-01

Tried with the below query and  0 is getting appended only for the 1st string.

```
select concat(substr("00000",0,10-length(colname)),colname) from table name;
```

Output: 01092-04-1.

Please suggest a solution. TIA.

Answer (score 3):

```
select concat_ws('-',
               lpad(your_col_splitted[0],5,'0'),
               lpad(your_col_splitted[1],3,'0'),
               lpad(your_col_splitted[2],2,'0')
               )
 from(              
 select split('1092-04-1','-') as your_col_splitted 
)s;
```

---

```
OK
01092-004-01
Time taken: 0.05 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Replace '1092-04-1' with your column.

Comment: `concat_ws` would be cleaner

Comment: Thanks, improved answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select  printf('%05d-%03d-%02d',x[0],x[1],x[2])

from    (select split('1092-04-1','-') as x) t 
;
```